# How to load a texture from a file?

Tags: sharpdx

I'm switching to SharpDX 3.0.0 right now. With the old SharpDX version you could load a texture from file in this way:

```
ShaderResourceView textureView = SharpDX.Direct3D11.Resource.FromFile<Texture2D>(device, "Texture.png");
```

or

```
ShaderResourceView textureView = ShaderResourceView.FromFile(device, "Texture.png");
```

But in version 3.0.0 the function FromFile is missing. How can I load textures from files with SharpDX 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the WIC API or similar methods. There is a old code [TextureLoader.cs](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/blob/master/StoreApp/OldSamplesToBeBackPorted/CommonDX/TextureLoader.cs) that performs a simplistic load (but doesn't handle format conversion)