# SharpDX 3.0.2 D3D11 - How to load texture from file and make it to work in shader?

Tags: c#, directx, directx-11, sharpdx

I have 0 experience with D3D. I am currently reading Frank Luna's book about D3D11 and trying to make examples working in C# using SharpDX though w/o effect framework. I stuck with texturing now. I don't understand how to load texture from file and how to send it to shader.

Official wiki is dead. Or at least it doesn't load for me.
I searched here but found only some way to do it with SharpDX.WIC which is with D2D so it looks a bit weird for me to use some D2D components in D3D app.

Comment: Same problem. I am just developing a Direct3D11 program but now I end up with D3DCompiler, Desktop, Direct2D1, DXGI, Mathematics. What is the purpose of having so many separated dependencies that will always be used together? Really annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here for the texture loader: [How to load a texture from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34925272/how-to-load-a-texture-from-a-file)

Usage:

```
var device = this.DeviceManager.Direct3DDevice;
var texture = TextureLoader.CreateTexture2DFromBitmap(device, TextureLoader.LoadBitmap(new SharpDX.WIC.ImagingFactory2(), "Texture2.png"));
ShaderResourceView textureView = new ShaderResourceView(device, texture);
```

Comment: Isn't it weird to use WIC which is part of Direct2D package for texture loading in Direct3D?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for posting on an old thread, but isn't it much better to use what is provided in .NET framework to achieve this?

```
    if (bitmap.PixelFormat != PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    {
        bitmap = bitmap.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    }
    var data = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    var ret = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D(device, new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2DDescription()
    {
        Width = bitmap.Width,
        Height = bitmap.Height,
        ArraySize = 1,
        BindFlags = SharpDX.Direct3D11.BindFlags.ShaderResource,
        Usage = SharpDX.Direct3D11.ResourceUsage.Immutable,
        CpuAccessFlags = SharpDX.Direct3D11.CpuAccessFlags.None,
        Format = SharpDX.DXGI.Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm,
        MipLevels = 1,
        OptionFlags = SharpDX.Direct3D11.ResourceOptionFlags.None,
        SampleDescription = new SharpDX.DXGI.SampleDescription(1, 0),
    }, new SharpDX.DataRectangle(data.Scan0, data.Stride));
    bitmap.UnlockBits(data);
    return ret;
```

Comment: Example above is good, but does not dispose bitmap.
Also, to acquire a bitmap, you should `using (var image = Image.FromFile(path)) { var bitmap = new Bitmap(image); ... }`

Answer (score 0):

WIC is not part of direct2d, wic is the best way to load images I know of in directX even in c++ you must use wic so just follow the link in the first answer and you will be fine.

Or

```
 public class TextureLoader
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Loads a bitmap using WIC.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="deviceManager"></param>
    /// <param name="filename"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static SharpDX.WIC.BitmapSource LoadBitmap(SharpDX.WIC.ImagingFactory2 factory, string filename)
    {
        var bitmapDecoder = new SharpDX.WIC.BitmapDecoder(
            factory,
            filename,
            SharpDX.WIC.DecodeOptions.CacheOnDemand
            );

        var formatConverter = new SharpDX.WIC.FormatConverter(factory);

        formatConverter.Initialize(
            bitmapDecoder.GetFrame(0),
            SharpDX.WIC.PixelFormat.Format32bppPRGBA,
            SharpDX.WIC.BitmapDitherType.None, 
            null,
            0.0, 
            SharpDX.WIC.BitmapPaletteType.Custom);

        return formatConverter;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a <see cref="SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D"/> from a WIC <see cref="SharpDX.WIC.BitmapSource"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="device">The Direct3D11 device</param>
    /// <param name="bitmapSource">The WIC bitmap source</param>
    /// <returns>A Texture2D</returns>
    public static SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D CreateTexture2DFromBitmap(SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device device, SharpDX.WIC.BitmapSource bitmapSource)
    {
        // Allocate DataStream to receive the WIC image pixels
        int stride = bitmapSource.Size.Width * 4;
        using (var buffer = new SharpDX.DataStream(bitmapSource.Size.Height * stride, true, true))
        {
            // Copy the content of the WIC to the buffer
            bitmapSource.CopyPixels(stride, buffer);
            return new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D(device, new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2DDescription()
            {
                Width = bitmapSource.Size.Width,
                Height = bitmapSource.Size.Height,
                ArraySize = 1,
                BindFlags = SharpDX.Direct3D11.BindFlags.ShaderResource,
                Usage = SharpDX.Direct3D11.ResourceUsage.Immutable,
                CpuAccessFlags = SharpDX.Direct3D11.CpuAccessFlags.None,
                Format = SharpDX.DXGI.Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm,
                MipLevels = 1,
                OptionFlags = SharpDX.Direct3D11.ResourceOptionFlags.None,
                SampleDescription = new SharpDX.DXGI.SampleDescription(1, 0),
            }, new SharpDX.DataRectangle(buffer.DataPointer, stride));
        }
    }
}
```

I just pulled it from the link so it may need some changes to work with SharpDX 3,i use almost the same code path but I have more options in the loading stage eg. non-premultiplied for normals, convert to Srgb and stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like to keep some textures in resources (inside exe). To get the bitmap from resources you can use YOURPROJECT.Properties.Resources.BITMAPNAME in C#.

Then I've made a little converter function for GDI+ bitmaps to WIC bitmap:

```
    public static unsafe SharpDX.WIC.Bitmap CreateWICBitmapFromGDI(
        System.Drawing.Bitmap gdiBitmap)
    {
        var wicFactory = new ImagingFactory();
        var wicBitmap = new SharpDX.WIC.Bitmap(
            wicFactory, gdiBitmap.Width, gdiBitmap.Height,
            SharpDX.WIC.PixelFormat.Format32bppBGRA, 
            BitmapCreateCacheOption.CacheOnLoad);

        System.Drawing.Rectangle rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(
            0, 0, gdiBitmap.Width, gdiBitmap.Height);
        var btmpData = gdiBitmap.LockBits(rect,
            System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
            System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        byte* pGDIData = (byte*)btmpData.Scan0;
        using (BitmapLock bl = wicBitmap.Lock(BitmapLockFlags.Write))
        {
            byte* pWICData = (byte*)bl.Data.DataPointer;
            for (int y = 0; y < gdiBitmap.Height; y++)
            {
                int offsetWIC = y * bl.Stride;
                int offsetGDI = y * btmpData.Stride;
                for (int x = 0; x < gdiBitmap.Width; x++)
                {
                    pWICData[offsetWIC + 0] = pGDIData[offsetGDI + 0];  //R
                    pWICData[offsetWIC + 1] = pGDIData[offsetGDI + 1];  //G
                    pWICData[offsetWIC + 2] = pGDIData[offsetGDI + 2];  //B
                    pWICData[offsetWIC + 3] = pGDIData[offsetGDI + 3];      //A
                    offsetWIC += 4;
                    offsetGDI += 4;
                }
            }
        }

        gdiBitmap.UnlockBits(btmpData);

        return wicBitmap;
    }
```

This will create WIC bitmap for you and then you can use CreateTexture2DFromBitmap to use it in your drawing pipeline.